# What keeps ports 32003 and 25419 open on my Ubuntu 14?

Tags: networking

I did a netstat on udp ports and found a service on port 32003 and one at 25419. What are they , how can I kill them at startup if they have no use?

[image]

Comment: Run `lsof -i :32003` for finding the process that opened the port. Same goes to port 25419, just change the port number.

Comment: Both belong to the dhclient command.

Comment: That means the ports are being used to query for IP addresses to DHCP server. Any Dhclient port should not be blocked at startup if you don't have any manual IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the process using the port with:

```
sudo netstat -lnp | grep :32003
sudo netstat -lnp | grep :25419
```

Comment: Thanks , just a beginner here here. They both belong to 1000/dhclient. What is this process responsible for?

Comment: @Esref: The **-p** switch of `netstat` would not always be able to resolve PID/Process name. Moreover this won't show any process not owned by user.

Comment: If I run the command as ROOT would it be able to see all processes?

Comment: @Xandarian: Yes, you will. But the Process name resolution would not always work.

Comment: @heemayl, I didn't know -p wouldn't always work. Thanks a lot :)